# Porting Subclass of Unicode to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm porting a legacy codebase from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6. In that codebase I have a number of instances of things like:

```
class EntityName(unicode):

    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, s):
        clean = cls.strip_junk(s)
        return super(EntityName, cls).__new__(cls, clean)

    def __init__(self, s):
        self._clean = s
        self._normalized = normalized_name(self._clean)
        self._simplified = simplified_name(self._clean)
        self._is_all_caps = None
        self._is_all_lower = None
        super(EntityName, self).__init__(self._clean)
```

It might be called like this:

```
EntityName("Guy DeFalt")
```

When porting this to Python 3 the above code fails because `unicode` is no longer a class you can extend (at least, if there is an equivalent class I cannot find it). Given that `str` is unicode now, I tried to just swap `str` in, but the parent init doesn't take a the string value I'm trying to pass:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

This makes sense because `str` does not have an `__init__` method - this does not seem to be an idiomatic way of using this class. So my question has two major branches:

- Is there a better way to be porting classes that sub-classed the old unicode class?
- If subclassing `str` is appropriate, how should I modify the `__init__` function for idiomatic behavior?

Comment: How is it used? Does it actually still need to subclass anything?

Comment: Maybe UserString from the collections module?

Comment: @megalng I'll check that out! Thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That had occurred to me, but it's a little hard to tell given all the places it's used in the codebase. I was going to go down that route next, but was hoping for a cleaner option.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Subclassing a string or anything else is very convenient when you later need to pass the instance to something that expect a string. From the code same this could be exactly the case.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to subclass a string or another immutable class in Python 3 is same as in Python 2:

```
class MyString(str):
  def __new__(cls, initial_arguments): # no staticmethod
     desired_string_value = get_desired_string_value(initial_arguments)
     return super(MyString, cls).__new__(cls, desired_string_value)
     # can be shortened to super().__new__(...)
  def __init__(self, initial_arguments): # arguments are unused
     self.whatever = whatever(self)
     # no need to call super().__init__(), but if you must, do not pass arguments
```

There are several issues with your sample. First, why `__new__` is `@staticmethod`? It's `@classmethod`, although you don't need to specify this. Second, the code seems to operate under the assumption that when you call `__new__` of the superclass, it somehow calls your `__init__` as well. I'm deriving this from looking at how `self._clean` is supposed to be set. This is not the case. When you call `MyString(arguments)`, the following happens:

- First Python calls `__new__` with the class parameter (usually called `cls`) and `arguments`. `__new__` must return the class instance. To do this it can create it, as we do, or do something else; e.g. it may return an existing one or, in fact, anything.
- Then Python calls `__init__` with the instance it received from `__new__` (this parameter is usually called `self`) and the same `arguments`.
- (There's a special case: Python won't call `__init__` if `__new__` returned something that is not a subclass of the passed class.)

Python uses class hierarchy to see which `__new__` and `__init__` to call. It's up to you to correctly sort out the arguments and use proper superclass calls in these two methods.